Installing two WSL instances on non-C drive point to the same instance
Following the steps outlined here, I downloaded and installed both Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 20.04. The Ubuntu 22.04 is a successful install and when I hit ubuntu.exe it brings me into it as expected. However, when I execute the ubuntu.exe inside the ubuntu20 folder, instead of starting a new ubuntu 20.04 instance it just brings me into the 22.04 instance. What is happening?
edit:
When I installed Ubuntu 22.04 it created with a distro with the name "Ubuntu". I suspect that when I am launching Ubuntu 20.04 it is also just launching "Ubuntu". How can I change this?

You can't have the two instances with the same name.  So what instances is WSL aware of? [Edit] your question to reflect this information. I suspect what you are running is just the "current" version, whatever that might be.

This might be the issue, when I installed Ubuntu 22.04 it created with a distro with the name "Ubuntu". I suspect that when I am launching Ubuntu 20.04 it is also just launching "Ubuntu". How can I change this?

You export and import that instance as a different name, but you have not provided enough information, to answer your question.

@Ramhound I followed the steps outlined in the other question I linked. This method does not use --import and therefore does not allow me to select a name (or at least it's not obvious how).

I asked awhile ago for the names of the instances you have installed.

I followed the steps outlined in the other question I linked. As mentioned in my question, it became installed as "Ubuntu". I did not specify the name, if not the question would most likely be solved by specifying a different name. So I suspect those .appx files might already have a name baked into them ?
